# Setup configuration for hibernate using java instead of xml files

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using hibernate to access our databases. Currently i am using the basic way to configure hibernate properties which is using xml files. I am building a library which will be accessed by many other frameworks to access databases. So providing path of xml files cant be an option.

Is there a way that we can provide all the configuration parameters in a java itself so that all the configuration stays in a java file and i am not dependent on the xml file. While researching i found a link:http://vladmihalcea.com/the-minimal-configuration-for-testing-hibernate/ This can be useful but is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't see what you are asking for... I mean, you do have a link to an example that seems to fullfill all the criteria (pun not intended).

Comment: Are you talking about hibernate mapping (hbm) or database connection parameters?

Comment: the link you provided has the answer to your question. there only 2 ways, declaratively using properties/xml or programmatic using Java code for which the link you posted has the info.